# What is the second derivative of $\sin(m \ln(x))$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find a general Taylor Series for $y=\sin(m \ln(x))$ (where $m$ is a non-zero constant) however my answer conflicts with the answer in the worked example and I cant find the error in my differentiation.

Comment: If you provided the calculations, it would be easier for everyone to help you find the error

Comment: This function cannot have a Taylor series around $0$ !

Comment: Did you use chain rule

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave us the first derivative which you found

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  y   &=  \sin(m\ln x) \\
  y'  &=  \cos(m\ln x) \cdot \frac{m}{x} \\
  y'' &= -\sin(m\ln x) \cdot \frac{m^{2}}{x^{2}}+
          \cos(m\ln x) \cdot \frac{-m}{x^{2}} \\
      &= -\frac{m}{x^{2}} \left[ m\sin (m\ln x)+\cos (m\ln x) \right]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint: the composite functions rule**

Derive $f(g(x))$ with respect upon $x$:

$$\frac{\text{d}f(g(x))}{\text{d}x} = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$

In your case: $f = \sin$ and $g = m\ln(x)$

Thence:

$$D_1 = \cos(m\ln(x))\cdot \frac{m}{x} = \frac{m\cos(m\ln(x))}{x}$$

Now it's about the rule for derivatives of fractions:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{[g(x)]^2}$$

Clearly, in doing that thou'll have to take into account of what $f$ and $g$ are in your case. Try to do it, I'll post the solution anyway.

**Solution**

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \frac{m\cos(m\ln(x))}{x} & = 
\frac{m}{x^2}\left[-m\sin(m\ln(x)) - \cos(m\ln(x))\right]
\end{align}
$$

That's the second derivative.

Comment: thanks that is what I have however my answer book suggests that there is a X multiplied with the cos(m ln x)

Comment: @AbdelgaderEldaw The book is wrong. My result is correct!